# convert the datetime stamp in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

This might be simple but I had no luck finding the right solution.
I have a 'date' column in np array with dates in format 'Tue Feb 04 17:04:01 +0000 2020' which I would like to convert to '2020-02-04 17:04:01'

Are there any inherent methods in np which does that?

There are solutions which suggested looping through the elements in the column, but I guess that's not Numpy - thonic way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try **dateutil** to parse dates

```
from dateutil import parser

date_str = 'Tue Feb 04 17:04:01 +0000 2020'
new_date = parser.parse(date_str).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %T')
```

With NumPy maybe you do as below:

```
np.datetime64(new_date)
#Example
date_str = 'Tue Feb 04 17:04:01 +0000 2020'
date_str2 = 'Fri Feb 07 17:04:01 +0000 2020'
new_date = parser.parse(date_str).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %T')
new_date2 = parser.parse(date_str2).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %T')

np.arange(np.datetime64(new_date), np.datetime64(new_date2))
```

Comment: how can we use this with np array without having to loop through the entire element?

Comment: Please see the answer by using numpy method.